# How do I check if an associative array exists in Bash >=5.2?

Tags: bash

In bash 5.1 I can use `-v` to check if an associative array exists:

```
bash-5.1# declare -A a
bash-5.1# a[foo]=bar
bash-5.1# [[ -v a[@] ]]; echo $?
0
```

But after upgrading to bash 5.2, I can no longer do this:

```
bash-5.2# declare -A a
bash-5.2# a[foo]=bar
bash-5.2# [[ -v a[@] ]]; echo $?
1
```

This change has broken most of my scripts, but I cannot figure out a way to get this functionality back.

Edit:
Please see discussion of this change: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-04/msg00058.html

tl;dr `test -v` now treats '@' as a literal key when used with an associative array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test whether a variable named `foo` is declared as an associative array:

```
[[ ${foo@a} = A ]]
```

The `a` parameter transformation is described in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section of the manual (scroll all the way down).

And to test if it is not empty:

```
[[ ${#foo[@]} -gt 0 ]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the shell to exit if `set -u` (`nounset`) is in effect and `foo` is not defined. You can precede the `${foo@a}` test with `[[ " ${!foo*} " == *" foo "* ]]` to check if a `foo` var is defined. (`${!foo*}` expands to all the var names starting with foo).

If possible, the problem can be avoided by always defining a default for the var at the start of your script, so that you never need to test if it's unset.